# SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table:staffreg)

Tags: java

I created a desktop app that uses sqlite as database with file extension as .db, when I run from netbeans, it inserts and performs all the functions to database , but when I make i a jar file using clean and build and try to login from the jar file it throws "SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table:staffreg)" exception

Comment: And the answer is that : "you have problem connecting to the database." Hope this helps :)

Comment: Good one @dbl ..